# Xcode (swift) vs Unity for isometric 2d mobile-apps - Performace, Package Size

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, unity-game-engine

Let's assume I want to develop an isometric 2D mobile-game such as Clash of Clans for example.
My main target would be iOS but of course Android would be nice, too (but not a must-have).
Now I have to decide to either program with Apples XCode (therefore Swift as a language, which I am already pretty familiar with), or develop my game with Unity3D (and therefore C# as a language, which I am also pretty familiar with).
Personally, I don't prefer one over the other.

So much for the set-up.

As I don't have any preferences, I'd like to choose the one that offers the most benefits for my 2.5D game to me.

The questions:

- Is there a difference in getting an approval for the App-Store if you program in Swift, or use Unity; C#?
- How big is the difference of the published package-size of the app between Unity and XCode?
- Does my Unity-written app run as smoothly as my XCode-written app?

I hope you could help me with that.

If I missed some points there, feel free to criticize me and give me your opinions on it.

Greetings
Chriz

Comment: Can't say about getting approval on App Store. But when you build you game to iOS target with Unity, it creates an xCode project for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Is there a difference in getting an approval for the App-Store if you program in Swift, or use Unity; C#?

No, given this general comparison - there should be nothing here favoring or disallowing one over the other.

- How big is the difference of the published package-size of the app between Unity and Xcode?

That is very hard to say.  There will be added libraries for Unity inclusion whereas Apple would already have shared libraries apart of the OS - used by every app.  Think shared libraries here - only Apple is permitted to do this. Not to be confused with the to be newly released iOS 9 'App Thinning'.

The larger weight will be media/images/bitmaps.

- Does my Unity-written app run as smoothly as my XCode-written app?

Since they both end up using OpenGL, the end result **should** be the same or very similar.  Obviously as the OS and device mature - if Unity doesn't leverage it, they could end up giving up performance advantages.

But... the flip side of being so tightly coupled with Swift/iOS/Apple, is you abandon your Android market - and if you are even considering it - I'd suggest Unity based on what you shared if there is a remote possibility you want to deploy to Android, desktops, *TV devices in the future.

Comment: Hey, do you know if Apple TVOS is supported by unity yet?

Comment: According to their blog, they are testing with key partners:  http://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/09/14/unity-is-coming-to-apple-tv/